# clearInterval and resolve() not working if executed from class

Tags: javascript

My class:

```
var indexedDBInitInterval; // clearInterval Doesnt work when done from within class for some reason..
var coumter  = 1;

class IndexedDBWrapper {
  constructor() {
    this._db = undefined
    this._dbInitInterval = undefined
    this.dbInitRequest = indexedDB.open("someDB", 1)
    this.dbInitRequest.onerror = (event) => { this.dbInitRequestOnError(event) }
    this.dbInitRequest.onsuccess = (event) => { this.dbInitRequestOnSuccess(event) }
    this.dbInitRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => { this.dbInitRequestOnUpgradedeNeeded(event) }
  }

  isDBInitalized() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      indexedDBInitInterval = setInterval(() => {
        log(this.dbInitRequest)
        log(this.dbInitRequest.readyState)
        log(indexedDBInitInterval)
        coumter = coumter + 1
        if (this.dbInitRequest.readyState == "done") {
          log("mutants")
          log(coumter)
          log(clearInterval(indexedDBInitInterval))
          resolve()
        }
      }, 300)
    })
  }

  dbInitRequestOnError(event) {
    log("Error initializing IndexedDB: ")
    log(event)
  }
```

And calling with:

```
indexedDBWrapper.isDBInitalized().then(() => {
```

Neither clearInterval or resolve gets fired, even tho `log("mutants")` gets fired.

What a puzzle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to make `indexedDBInitInterval` a variable within `isDBInitialized`. Otherwise if you call the function multiple (times or even on multiple objects), they would interfere with each other. The same can be said for `coumter`, although that might just be a debug variable.

Does `indexedDBWrapper.isDBInitalized().then(() => console.log('OK'))` print `OK`? I can understan the `clearInterval` failing if the wrong `indexedDBInitInterval` is used, but `mutants` being logged should indicate that `resolve()` also gets called, unless an error happens in between.

Comment: Things within `...then()` dont get fired :// I moved the `indexedDBInitInterval ` to global scope for debugging, originally it was class variable

Comment: In that case, no idea. Since that `log("mutants")` is successful and there aren't any (uncaught) errors, the following statement should also be executed.

Comment: nvm, you where right. the OK got fired and it was becouse of duplicate issue.